# Narrator reads out "No item in view" in angular application

Tags: angular, narrator

Earlier the angular application app worked fine.

Some changes are done in core files, that is, grand-parent html tags, now the Narrator reads out for div element:

> "No item in view"

The changes include newer angular version from 6 to 7, but it does not look like it is the reason as it issue occurred a day before the upgrade. But there might be minor 6.x updates because of the updates to npm.

App needs to run on Edge browser.

If you had a similar issue, share your thoughts, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question as per https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Even when everything is ok, when testing in Chrome you will get "No item in view" error.

When testing in Edge browser, you wont get any error. (while listening to your app using Narrator, `Ctrl+Win+Enter` to start/stop in Win10)

Use `tabindex` & `role`, depending on what html element, one of the below may work:

```
<div tabindex="0" role="heading">A</div>
<div tabindex="0" role="textbox">A</div>
<span tabindex="0" role="alert">A</span>
<span tabindex="0" role="heading">A</span>
<p tabindex="0" role="presentation"></p>
<a tabindex="0" role="link">A</a>
<a tabindex="0" xrole="menuitem">A</a>
<ul tabindex="0" role="menu"><li tabindex="0" role="menuitem">A</li></ul>
<header tabindex="0" role="banner">A</header>
<footer tabindex="0" role="contentinfo">A</footer>
NOTE: Above not perfect to the syntax.
```

Add `aria-label` or `attr.aria-label`, when text is different, one wil work for you:

```
<div tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-label="Text2">Text1</div>
    OR
<div tabindex="0" role="heading" attr.aria-label="Text2">Text1</div>
```

For Edge, all working fine.
For Chrome browser, `div`/`span` may not work, then change them to `h1, h2, etc` & override the look with css.

Hope that helped. Feel free to update this answer, so it becomes more complete, others will waste less time.